# UIAlertVIew in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview

```
-(IBAction) secondTwoSlotSettings: (id)sender{
        UIAlertView *secondTwoSlotSettings = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                        message:@""
                                                                       delegate:self
                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"キャンセル"
                                                              otherButtonTitles:@"2スロット カメラ",@"2スロット カメラロール", nil];

        [secondTwoSlotSettings show];   
    }

    -(IBAction) firstTwoSlotSettings: (id)sender{
        UIAlertView *firstTwoSlotSettingsMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                              message:@""
                                                                             delegate:self
                                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"キャンセル"
                                                                    otherButtonTitles:@"1スロット",@"２スロット", nil];

        [firstTwoSlotSettingsMessage show];   

    }


    -(IBAction) oneSlotSettings: (id)sender{
        UIAlertView *oneSlotSettingsMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                         message:@""
                                                                        delegate:self
                                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"キャンセル"
                                                               otherButtonTitles:@"カメラ",@"カメラロール", nil];

        [oneSlotSettingsMessage show];   
    }


    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];


        if([title isEqualToString:@"キャンセル"])
        {

            NSLog(@"キャンセル was selected.");
        }
        else if([title isEqualToString:@"はい"])
        {
            NSLog(@"はい was selected.");
        }
        else if([title isEqualToString:@"2スロット カメラ"])
        {
            NSLog(@"2スロット カメラ was selected.");
        }

        else if([title isEqualToString:@"1スロット"])
        {
            NSLog(@"1スロット was selected.");


        }
        else if([title isEqualToString:@"2スロット"])
        {
            NSLog(@"2スロット was selected.");
            UIAlertView *oneSlotSettingsMessage = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                                                                             message:@""
                                                                            delegate:self
                                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"キャンセル"
                                                                   otherButtonTitles:@"2スロット カメラ",@"2スロット カメラロール", nil];

            [oneSlotSettingsMessage show];   

        }
        else if([title isEqualToString:@"カメラ"])
        {
            NSLog(@"カメラ was selected.");




        }
        else if ([title isEqualToString:@"カメラロール"])
        {
            NSLog(@"カメラロール was selected.");


    }
```

Here is my code:

I was only able to show the firstTwoSlotSettings and oneSlotSettings. but when I try to show the secondTwoSlotSettings it vanish.

Comment: Why do you need this? Probably it has other solution.

Comment: what is your requirement ?can you explain?

Comment: What do you mean by " UIAlertVIew in UIAlertView " ? please elaborate...

Comment: hi, I dont understand what do you want to accomplish, an alert inside an alert?, or an alert after first alert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No It is not possible with Apple's UIAlertView. When you present an alertView ,it will come modal to all other views and dismiss any other Alerts already present in the screen.

One thing you can do is to create a custom View as your alert and animates its present/dismiss action? Then you have the control to do whatever you want..

Comment: Okay thanks. I was planning on this too, but I was thinking of an easy way I thought AlertView in a AlertView is possible. So I'm gonna stick to your idea. Thanks. :)